# How to set the right height for a img tag in WebView

Tags: android, html, webview

I get the html format data and the picture's information from the server, the html string has set the width of the img tag to 100%, now I need to download the pictures using Android-Universal-Image-Loader lib, and then use Js to update the img's src, before the the picture was downloaded and update to the WebView, I need to set the img'height to a scale size in px to hold the space.

I have got the real size of the picture from the server, and I try to get the scale height by this:

```
int scaleHeight = (int)((double)realHeight / (double)(realWidth / mScreemWidth))
```

but when I update the scaleHeight to the img's height, it shows the img was stretch in vertical.

I want to ask, is't my calculation is wrong, or my way is not correct, if it's, is there any ways to let the img tag hold the space, before displaying the real picture.

As my poor english, I hope I have let you understand my question.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Is `mScreenWidth` a double or an int? If int, then cast it to a double.

Comment: the mScreenWidht is an int, and I have try to convert to double , and it's useless, I wonder if my way is correct

Comment: You need to cast it to a double for the math to work correctly. Your equation is right.

Comment: Yes, I have do what you said,  but it still stretch in vertical, I update the img height to scaleHeight in px.

Comment: Can you update your question with your new code?

Comment: I have found a way to get the webview's width, it's not equal the screen's width, so that the when I use the screen width to calculation the img height, it stretch in vertical. But I have another problem.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31259560/how-to-get-the-width-of-a-page-in-webview